# Django template tag "if" statement not evaluating correctly trying a simple search

Tags: django, django-templates

So on my website I want to allow people to search through people who have registered for an account.
The goal of this code is to try to sort through all matching usernames, first_names, and last_names.
The problem is, my if statements won't seem to evaluate the way they should in my templates. For example:

I would like to first evaluate if q matches to username, first_name, and last_name,

then evaluate if q= username and last_name and not first_name,

then q= username=first_name and not last_name,

then q=username and not first_name or last_name,

then q= first_name and last_name and not username,

then q=last_name but not username or first_name,

and finally q=first_name and not username or last_name.

I created several test users including ones with the following information:

username=testuser1, first_name=Jason, last_name=Smith
username=newperson, first_name=frank, last_name=testuser2

so if I do a search, for example, for "testuser", the results would show

Username:testuser1  Name: Jason Smith
and it would state that "testuser", q, was in the username, first_name, and last_name. The other user i created, "newperson" also doesn't show up under the search results.  However if i search tesuser2, newperson will show up,
but it will state that "testuser2" is the firstname, when i set it up as the last name.  Here is my code:

```
#views.py

def search_people(request):
    errors1 = []
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        ...
        #Code evlauating errors
        ...
    else:
        usernames = RegisterProfile.objects.filter(user__username__icontains=q)
        last_names = RegisterProfile.objects.filter(last_name__icontains=q)
        first_names = RegisterProfile.objects.filter(first_name__icontains=q)
    ...

#search_results.html

{% if usernames or first_names or last_names %}
    <p>The following members matched your search results:</p>
    {% if usernames and first_names and last_names %}
        {% for username in usernames %}
            <li>Username:{{ username.user.username }} First Name: {{ username.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ username.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
            <li>q is in all three</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if usernames and last_names and not first_names %}
        {% for username in usernames %}
            <li>Username:{{ username.user.username }} First Name: {{ username.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ username.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
            <li>q is in username and last name</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} 
    {% if usernames and first_names and not last_names %}
        {% for username in usernames %}
            <li>Username:{{ username.user.username }} First Name: {{ username.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ username.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
            <li>q is in username and first name</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if usernames and not first_names %}
        {% if not last_names %}
            {% for username in usernames %}
                <li>Username:{{ username.user.username }} First Name: {{ username.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ username.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
                <li>q is only in username</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if last_names and first_names and not usernames %}
        {% for last_name in last_names %}
            <li>Username:{{ last_name.user.username }} First Name: {{ last_name.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ last_name.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
            <li>q is in first and last name</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if last_names and not first_names %}
        {% if not usernames %}  
            {% for last_name in last_names %}
                <li>Username:{{ last_name.user.username }} First Name: {{ last_name.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ last_name.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
                <li>q is only in last name</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if first_names and not last_names %}
        {% if not usernames %}  
            {% for first_name in first_names %}
                <li>Username:{{ first_name.user.username }} First Name: {{ first_name.user.get_profile.first_name }} {{ first_name.user.get_profile.last_name }}</li>
                <li>q is only in first name</li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endif %}
```

I know this is long, and might not be the best way to do it, but I am open to any advice and appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I essentially want to just be able to see if the search input q is in either the username, first_name, or last name, then in my template display all matching results, without any repeats of the same user.  I don't necessarily care how to go about accomplishing this, as long as it works.  I thought my solution would be simple enough and should work, but for unknown reasons, it doesn't work right.  I hope that helps to clarify things and explain my attempted solution if there was any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matches = RegisterProfile.objects.filter(
     Q(user__username__icontains=q)
    |Q(last_name__icontains=q)
    |Q(first_name__icontains=q)
)

<p>The following members matched your search results:</p>
{% for profile in matches %}
<li>Username: {{ profile.user.username }} Name: {{ profile.first_name }} {{ profile.last_name }}</li>
<li>q is in 
    {% if q in profile.user.username %}username, {% endif %}
    {% if q in profile.first_name %}first name, {% endif %}
    {% if q in profile.last_name %}last name.{%endif%}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This could be cleaned up some, but the building blocks are there.  For instance, if q is just in username you will get a line like "q is in username,".  Also, I've assumed that RegisterProfile is your user profile, so I left out the profile.user.get_profile bit.  If that isn't the case, you may need to re-add that.

I think the key piece you were missing is the [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) stuff. Those allow you to do more complex things than 'AND' in your filters.

Comment: I read the link you posted and tried using what you had suggested, however it still doesn't work the way I would expect it to work.  for instance, some of the users I search for don't show up, and the part: {% if q in profile.user.username %} part always shows up blank

Comment: I was trying to keep it a little less complicated, but in reality I have two user types, and they both extend a BaseProfile model. I tried student_matches = StudentRegisterProfile..., and teacher_matches = TeacherRegisterProfile... then i repeated your template code for "user_matches" and "broadcaster_matches" instead of "matches", however if I type {{ profile.user_type }} in my template, it will say "teacher" even for registered students. I know i have the registration correct because I have been using it to differentiate usertypes in other templates. thanks for the input. any other thoughts?

Comment: It's likely you're dealing with more than one problem here. There are a number of ways to deal with model inheritance, and it sounds like you've likely used an abstract base with two subclasses and a type field to do your profiles.  I think the {{profile.user_type}} issue might be a misconfiguration in that department.  I notice you're using case insensitive filters, so it's possible `q in profile.user.username` fails because it is case sensitive. Since django templates just give you `''` if an attribute is missing, profile.user or user.username may not even exist.

Comment: I think your best bet at this point is to focus on one of those at a time, and create a minimal code sample that causes the problem. I saw a great link today that applies here: http://sscce.org/. It is easy to build upon a simple example once you get the root problem solved. If you end up opening new questions, you should link them in your original question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  I was able to get it figured out using Q objects.  It works great now.  I just made a stupid error the first time trying it in my view (i.e. I set {'teacher_matches': teacher_matches, 'user_matches': teacher_matches}).  That was why only teacher results would show up. Q objects worked beautifully and made my code more concise as well. Thanks again - saved me a huge headache.